# Only join tables if certain value does not exist among multiple rows in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I try to join two tables. One is table filled with totally unique variables `debtor`. No duplicates of the debtor id can exist.
Now I wish to join it with the `items` table where the `debtor.debtor` id can appear multiple times.

What I wish to do is to only join if the item `'20004'` does not exist in the order history

I have the following sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0826/1/0

```
create table items
 (
 debtor int,
 item int,
 qty int,
 invoice int
 );
create table debtor
 (
 debtor int,
 name varchar(255)
 );
insert into debtor(debtor, name)
VALUES ('1000','Mister blue'),
 ('1001','Mister Orange'),
 ('1002','Mister Red'),
 ('1003','Mister Yellow'),
 ('1004','Mister Green');
INSERT INTO items (debtor, item,qty, invoice)
values ('1000','20001','1','1'),
 ('1000','20002','1','1'),
 ('1000','20003','1','1'),
 ('1000','20004','1','1'),
 ('1000','20005','1','1'),

 ('1001','20001','1','2'),
 ('1001','20002','1','2'),
 ('1001','20003','1','2'),

 ('1001','20005','1','2'),

 ('1002','20001','1','3'),
 ('1002','20002','1','3'),
 ('1002','20003','1','3'),
 ('1002','20004','1','3'),
 ('1002','20005','1','3'),
 ('1002','20006','1','3'),

 ('1003','20001','1','4'),
 ('1003','20002','1','4'),
 ('1003','20003','2','4'),
 ('1003','20004','1','4'),
 ('1003','20005','1','4');
```

And I do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM debtor
JOIN items on debtor.debtor = items.debtor AND items.item != '20004'
```

But I still get all the invoice lines that are not `'20004'`.

How can I perform the query in a way that the join will not performed if the value `'20004'` does not appear?

My preferred answer that should come from the query should be that only **mr Orange** should appear.

Who can help me?

Comment: What columns do you actually need in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM debtor d
JOIN items i on d.debtor = i.debtor 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT debtor 
   FROM items i2
   WHERE item = '20004' AND i2.debtor = i.debtor
   )
```

Update fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0826/12/0

Comment: Thank you Tanner for the answer and the updated fiddle, this is exactly what I need. Fast and good.

Answer (score 2):

Or this:

```
select * from debtor d
join items i on d.debtor = i.debtor 
where d.debtor not in (select debtor from items where item = '20004');
```

Comment: Thank you Kirill for your answer. I didn't choose to accept your answer on the basis that your method is slightly slower than the one given by Tanner. But thank you for your effort!

Answer (score -1):

if you want only the invoices that are '200004' you should use

```
SELECT * FROM debtor
JOIN items on debtor.debtor = items.debtor AND items.item = '20004'
```

you used != instead ... probably just a typo ...

Comment: That isn't what they want. Returns blue, red, yellow. They want orange.

Answer (score -1):

You should base your filter on debtor column because the 1001 id is Mister Orange.

```
SELECT * FROM debtor
JOIN items on debtor.debtor = items.debtor AND debtor.debtor = '1001'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0826/19/0

Comment: can't. It variables which product has to be excluded, so I would get different results. I do not know on beforehand which debtor I will get.
In the example I provided I made it clear that the expected result is mr orange, in the real word application, I would use hundreds of thousands of rows to dig through.